# Special multidimensional array

Tags: php, object, get

I have a difficult problem here (and I'm not sure that's possible).

I would like to call a class with the `__get` method:

```
$P = ClassName();
$P->A = 0.1;
$P->A->B = 0.5;
```

Which would return this:

`$P->A` should return `0.1` (and execute the `__get` method)

`$P->A->B` should return `0.5` (and execute the `__get` method on A)

Comment: How can be `$p->a` have a numeric value and be an object with parameters on its own at the same time? Honestly I am not sure what exactly you are asking

Comment: This isn't possible. When you call `$P->A->B`, the get method is just given the property name `A`, it doesn't get `A->B`, so it can't tell the difference between `$P->A` and `$P->A->B`.

Comment: The `->` operator can only be used on an object. `$P->a` will return a value type, so you can't take the result of that and access the property `B`.

Comment: Yes, that is my question/problem. Because of the 'object' type or A, getting $P->A will only return another Object (containing B). Here is why i want to know if there is a possible trick to do this.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this? There's probably a better way to go about it.

Comment: You might be able to use the magic method [__toString()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring) for that (so when you want to output `$p->a` it returns a specific value)

Comment: I have millions of probabilities like : P(A) = 0.1 // P(A|B) = 0.5 ...
I would like to use them via object. I could use some others methods, but it will be "hard" to use them in my app.

Comment: @kingkero Ah yes, why not. I could create nested array with __toString() method to get value. Thank's for the idea.

Comment: Also keep in mind that if you are experiencing big trouble with something in your code, maybe your implementation could be better if different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have

```
$P->A
```

return 1.5 is not a problem. You can do it with __get, though you do not have to. I do not believe, however you can do

```
$P->A->B
```

As "A" would be returning a number, not an object you would have nothing to call __get with. This, however would work:

```
$P->A->getValue()
$P->A->B
```

But there is **no way** to get around it and make the code work as is.

Comment: In context of HTTP there is: `__toString()` returning the value while ->A being an object. But you have to write the rest of the program in a very dedicated and strict manner.